# laravel database seed failing in easyPHP

Tags: php, laravel, easyphp, seeding

I have an easyPHP devserver with a mysql database and laravel set up. I have run two migrations to set up two tables in the database, 'properties' and 'property_images'.

I have two models made for properties and property_images.

Property.php:

```
class Property extends Eloquent {

   protected $fillable = array('id','title','type','description');

   public function propertyImages() {
      return $this->hasMany('PropertyImage');
   }
}
```

Property_image.php:

```
class Property extends Eloquent {

   public function property() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Property');
   }
}
```

I'm trying to seed the database with this file. Running `php artisan db:seed` runs the file and outputs everything before "Finished property table delete" and then nothing. It never finishes the command, like it's stuck in a loop.
Seed file:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

      $this->command->info('Starting');
      $this->call('PropertyTableSeeder');
      $this->command->info('Finished first seed');
      $this->call('PropertyImageTableSeeder');
      $this->command->info('Done seeding');
    }

}

class PropertyTableSeeder extends Seeder {
   public function run() {
      DB::table('properties')->delete();

      $this->command->info('Finished Property table delete'); //This line prints out fine

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'caseyTrail1',
            'title' => 'Casey Trail 1',
            'type' => 'residential',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Casey Trail 1.'
      ));

      $this->command->info('Created first property');  //Never reaches this output

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'caseyTrail2',
            'title' => 'Casey Trail 2',
            'type' => 'residential',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Casey Trail 2.'
      ));

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'castleResidence',
            'title' => 'Castle Residence',
            'type' => 'residential',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Castle Residence.'
      ));

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'ormandBeach',
            'title' => 'Ormand Beach',
            'type' => 'residential',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Ormand Beach.'
      ));

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'privateResidence1',
            'title' => 'Private Residence 1',
            'type' => 'residential',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Private Residence 1.'
      ));

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'assuranceTitle',
            'title' => 'Assurance Title',
            'type' => 'commercial',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Assurance Title.'
      ));

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'bethesda',
            'title' => 'Bethesda',
            'type' => 'commercial',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Bethesda.'
      ));

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'choiceBank',
            'title' => 'Choice Bank',
            'type' => 'commercial',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Choice Bank.'
      ));

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'dawesStreetApartments',
            'title' => 'Dawes Street Apartments',
            'type' => 'commercial',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Dawes Street Apartments.'
      ));

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'dublins',
            'title' => 'Dublins',
            'type' => 'commercial',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Dublins.'
      ));

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'langFinancial',
            'title' => 'Lang Financial',
            'type' => 'commercial',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Lang FInancial.'
      ));

      Property::create(array(
            'id' => 'skiersOutlet',
            'title' => 'Skiers Outlet',
            'type' => 'commercial',
            'description' => 'This is the description for Skiers Outlet.'
      ));

      $this->command->info('Finished Property run');
   }
}

class PropertyImageTableSeeder extends Seeder {
   public function run() {
      DB::table('property_images')->delete();

      PropertyImage::create(array(
            'property_id' => 'caseyTrail1',
            'filename' => 'picture1',
            'title' => 'Casey Trail 1 Picture 1'
      ));

      PropertyImage::create(array(
            'property_id' => 'caseyTrail1',
            'filename' => 'picture2',
            'title' => 'Casey Trail 1 Picture 2'
      ));

      PropertyImage::create(array(
            'property_id' => 'caseyTrail1',
            'filename' => 'picture3',
            'title' => 'Casey Trail 1 Picture 3'
      ));

      PropertyImage::create(array(
            'property_id' => 'caseyTrail2',
            'filename' => 'picture1',
            'title' => 'Casey Trail 2 Picture 1'
      ));

      PropertyImage::create(array(
            'property_id' => 'caseyTrail2',
            'filename' => 'picture2',
            'title' => 'Casey Trail 2 Picture 2'
      ));

      PropertyImage::create(array(
            'property_id' => 'caseyTrail2',
            'filename' => 'picture3',
            'title' => 'Casey Trail 2 Picture 3'
      ));
   }
}
```

When I let the command run awhile it finally gives this error output:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\cwa>php
 artisan db:seed
Failed loading D:\PROGRA~2\EASYPH~1.1VC\binaries\php\php_runningversion\php_xdeb
ug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9.dll
Starting
Finished Property table delete
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to all
ocate 32 bytes) in D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11\data\localw
eb\projects\cwa\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.
php on line 615
```

Comment: Is the class name a typo in Property_image.php or is it really wrong? I think that if your class tries to reference itself it might cause some recursion and if what I see up top is how it is in your code thats probably what's wrong.

Comment: We have a winner. :/ Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To test, please add this line to your DatabaseSeeder:

```
DB::disableQueryLog();
```

Before

```
$this->command->info('Starting');
```

Usually this make the php memory exhausted errors go away.

Comment: Added the line. Didn't change the result though. Thanks.